# How can i iterate over array of objects and change group label when its different than last one?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular2-ngfor

i have an array of objects that looks like this:

```
[
  {group_label: Colors, label: Red, value: '1'},
  {group_label: Colors, label: Green, value: '2'},
  {group_label: Sizes, label: S, value: '3'},
  {group_label: Sizes, label: M, value: '4'},
  {group_label: Sizes, label: L, value: '5'}
]
```

and i want to iterate over it with *ngFor and get this result:

```
Colors:
  Red: 1
  Green: 2
Sizes:
  S: 3
  M: 4
  L: 5
```

and my problem is, how do i show group_label only once at start of each "section". I cant reformat those objects to something more appropriate to this task as they are Angulars FormGroup in FormArrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a pipe to group these:

```js
@Pipe({name: 'group'})
export class GroupPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(values: Array<any>): Array<any> {
    // {group_label: Colors, label: Red, value: '1'}
    const groups = values.reduce((all, row) => {
      all[row.group_label] = all[row.group_label] || []; 
      all[row.group_label].push(row);
    }, {});
    return Object.keys(groups).map(group => ({ group_label: group, labels: groups[group]}));
  }
}
```

Now use nested ngFor:

```html
<div *ngFor="let group of (unsortedGroups | group)">
  {{ group.group_label }}
  <div *ngFor="let label of group.labels">
    {{ label.label }}: {{ label.value }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the only possible way to use two ngFor and make a custom pipe or a function with a group by functionality. After that you can write out your key value pairs with the second ngFor.

A least elegant way is to refer to the previous element by an index and and check if the group_label was different and create a new section of it was. In that case your array has to be sorted already!

Comment: hmm seems more complicated than adding next formArray to form builder as a "wrapper" :)